Orthogonal Vectors and Orthogonal Matrix
I'm confused about the definition of orthogonal matrix.
These vectors: ${v_1}=(0,0,1), {v_2}=(0,2,0), {v_1}=(3,0,0)$
are orthogonal since their dot products are zeros. Can we say $A=(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ is an orthogonal matrix given that $AA^T \neq I $? which is the definition of a orthogonal matrix: a matrix made up of orthogonal vectors or a matrix whose inverse equals to its transpose? Is there such thing as orthonormal matrix?

Orthogonal matrix means an orthonormal basis consisting of column-vectors. I do not think there is a common name for matrices where columns are just pairwise orthogonal.

Orthogonal matrices are defined as those where $AA^T=I$. This means their columns and rows are always orthonormal.

You are right in the sense that the vectors being pairwise orthogonal ($v_i \cdot v_j = 0$) is different than the set of vectors being orthonormal (previous property plus $\| v_i \| = 1$).
However, in the literature, both the terms orthonormal matrix and orthogonal matrix refer to a square matrix where its columns (as well as its rows) form an orthonormal set of vectors, i.e., square matrices $X$ where $X^T X = X X^T = I$.
Those matrices when the vectors are pairwise orthogonal but not orthonormal, are not of much interest apparently. There is no specific name for them.

A square matrix is considered orthogonal if its transpose is equal to its inverse matrix. You can also think about it as: if the product of a square matrix and its transpose gives an identity matrix it is orthogonal.
